# Grunt> promt is not showing after proper installation of pig and hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have configured hadoop.2.6.0 in vmware ubuntu machine and now i am configuring pig-0.12.0 all configuration steps seems proper but when finally i fire pig command on terminal it show blank space instead of Grunt> shell .

Comment: What *exactly* do you see on the terminal when you try to start pig? -- What happens when you try to run a simple pig script from a file?

Comment: Have you tried running in both local as well as MapReduce mode? What command are you calling to start Pig and what is the error?

Comment: installation problem is resolved now i was not running ./pig -x local from pig/bin its working in local mode but now it runs basic commands but when i am trying to load and store command are not working properly i have hadoop installed have name node and data node i am successfully store file in hadoop but they are not loading in pig i mean load command is not working properly

Comment: thanks dennis and summet to show intrest in my problem